# Изменение размеров виджетов

Tags: c++, qt

Как изменить размеры виджетов которые находятся в слое(layout),
получается изменить размеры кнопок через qss(пока я что попробовал), но размеры QWidget не получается я хочу сделать sideBar как в qt

Ps. Не предлагать setStrethFactor и подобное!

```
width: 70px;
```

Comment: У виджетов есть setMinimumSize(), есть setFixedSize(), еще можно настроить политику размера, чтобы, к примеру, виджет все доступное пространство заполнял: setSizePolicy(). Ссылка где можно про методы прочитать: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html

Comment: А почему на button работает qss width и height а на QWidget и QFrame не работает

Comment: Не знаю, могу придумать разные причины почему так происходит, добавьте ваш код в вопрос (так лучше всегда делать, когда вопрос касается проблем вашего кода :))

Comment: Блин Qt такой не удобный в отличии от Delphi

Comment: Не знаю, в чем вы видите неудобство и минусы Qt, мб просто не умете его готовить :) Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы любой мог запустить код и увидеть тот результат

Comment: @AimonZ. ну так и пишите на Delphi, в чём проблема ? =)

Comment: Там CSS НЕТ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi и Qt - вещи по разные стороны баррикад. Delphi позволяет разработать приложение в стиле [RAD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAD_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Но, когда дело доходит до детальной проработки - легче переписать не на Delphi. Библиотека Qt же позволяет проработать механику приложения основательно, напомню, что она включает три(!) способа создания пользовательского интерфейса, а именно:

- Qt Widgets - классический, выраженный манипуляцией классами C++
- QML - язык программирования, основанный на [QtScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtScript) и предоставляющий возможность разрабатывать современные пользовательские интерфейсы под сенсорные экраны
- Qt WebEngine - набор абстракции поверх [движка Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework), дающий возможность верстать пользовательские интерфейсы (привлечение специалистов React, VueJS, Angular из мира Web)

Что же касается данного случая, удобнее всего воспользоваться функцией автогенерации кода Qt Designer и получить готовый код формы, но оформленный в виде исходного кода C++.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSpacerItem>
#include <QDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog *Dialog = new QDialog();

    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QFrame *frame;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;

    Dialog->resize(400, 300);
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(Dialog);
    horizontalLayout->setSpacing(0);
    horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout"));
    horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    frame = new QFrame(Dialog);
    frame->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("frame"));
    frame->setMinimumSize(QSize(71, 0));
    frame->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-color: #242729;"));
    frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    frame->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);

    horizontalLayout->addWidget(frame);
    horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(326, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    horizontalLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer);

    Dialog->show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

После небольшого упрощения получается совсем простенький участок кода, помещающийся в функцию main(). Со временем, работая непосредственно с кодом, вопросы о неудобности способов простроения пользовательского интерфейса Qt отпадут сами собой...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]